# how to define a pandas dataframe to read images based on id stored in csv file?

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to create pandas dataframe and read images from a directory according to image IDs saved in a csv file. The csv file include image IDs and labels that will be later used for a regression task. When I load the script the images are not stored in the image variable. can anyone help me to correct this script?

```
labelPath =  "E:/Notebooks/labels.csv" #path for the csv file
cols = ["id","label"] #defining the columns name in the csv file
all_df = pd.read_csv(labelPath, sep=",", header=None, names=cols)

def read_img(self,id, folder='image_files'):
        
    images=[]
    """
    Read image by it's id
    """
    file='E:/Notebooks/' + folder + '/' + str(id) + '.tif'
    for filepath in os.listdir(file):
        images.append(cv2.imread(file+'/{0}'.format(filepath),flags=(cv2.IMREAD_ANYCOLOR | cv2.IMREAD_ANYDEPTH)))
    return images
```

update: an example for the data in the csv file

| ID | label |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 19.391862 |
| 2 | 7.681008 |
| 3 | 250.264396 |
| 4 | 412.548149 |
| .. | .. |
| .. | .. |
| 600 | 110.348484 |

Comment: Hi Rayan, please provide a reproducible piece of code, input and output sample; in that case it would be much easier to help you.

Comment: Hi Fabio, thanks for the reply. May I know what is lacking from the code included in the question? what extra information should be added?

Comment: Just try to put a sample of the .csv file, imagine that I have to be able to reproduce the issue you're facing. I don't know what data your file contains and what's your expected output.

Comment: Please see the update in the question

Comment: So, your files start with "E:/Notebooks/image_files/1.tif"?  No zero-padding in the name?  And since you're generating a complete file name, you don't need the `for filepath in os.listdir(file):` loop at all.  You're only reading one image.

Comment: Perhaps you should show us how you're calling this.  The fact that each call returns a list of one item suggests a problem.